# confused by use of nor in word problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I am working through a word problem that states:

"Suppose there are 50 beads in a drawer: 25 are glass, 30 are red, 20 are spherical,
18 are red glass, 12 are glass spheres, 15 are red spheres, and 8 are red glass
spheres. How many beads are neither red, nor glass, nor spheres?"

Wouldn't this condition translate to:

$\lnot Red \land \lnot Glass \land \lnot Sphere$ in which case, I am not sure how any of these beads would resolve to $True$.

At any rate, I am very confused - I assume I do not fully understand the logical nor.

Comment: A bead which is a blue plastic cube is neither red, nor glass, nor a sphere, that is to say it is not red and is not glass and is not a sphere. It would be counted in the $50$ total but not in the stated detail counts

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of the condition is correct. If you make a Venn diagram and use the information to fill in the numbers of beads in the various regions, you’ll find that the seven regions inside the three circles add up to fewer than $50$ beads, so there are in fact some beads that are neither red, nor glass, nor spherical. They are in the eighth region, the one *outside* all three circles.